# Get scroll position of UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a `UIPageViewController`, and I need to get the scroll position of the ViewController as the users swipe so I can partially fade some assets while the view is transitioning to the next `UIViewController`.

The delegate and datasource methods of `UIPageViewController` don't seem to provide any access to this, and internally I'm assuming that the `UIPageViewController` must be using a scroll view somewhere, but it doesn't seem to directly subclass it so I'm not able to call

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

}
```

I've seen some other posts suggestion to grab a reference to the `pageViewController!.view.subviews` and then the first index is a scrollView, but this seems *very* hacky. I'm wondering if there is a more standard way to handle this.

Comment: Can I ask why are you using the pageview controller then? Would a simple scrollview work instead?

Comment: I've generally found UIPageViewController to be extremely lacking both in functionality and in how much I can customize it. I almost always end up using a scroll view on collection view instead.

Comment: @Aggressor, I'm using pageViewController, because it provides near exacty built in functionality to the thing we are building, I could code it all in a UIScrollView, but I was hoping that pageViewController would be robust enough to provide this relatively simple feature, but it looks like it may not have it.

Comment: What specifically does it give that is lacking in a general scrollview? As mentioned above by AdamPro13, I too always use my own scrollviews.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can search for the UIScrollView inside your `UIPageViewController`. To do that, you will have to implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

After that you can get your scrollView:

```
for v in pageViewController.view.subviews{
    if v.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView){
        (v as UIScrollView).delegate = self
    }
}
```

After that, you are able to use all the UIScrollViewDelegate-methods and so you can override the `scrollViewDidScroll` method where you can get the scrollPosition:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   //your Code
}
```

---

Or if you want a **one-liner**:

```
let scrollView = view.subviews.filter { $0 is UIScrollView }.first as! UIScrollView
scrollView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 18):

UIPageViewController scroll doesn't work like normal scrollview and you can't get scrollView.contentOffset like other scrollViews.

so here is a trick to get what's going on when user scrolls :

first you have to find scrollview and set delegate to current viewController like other answers said.

```
class YourViewController : UIPageViewController {

    var startOffset = CGFloat(0) //define this

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         //from other answers   
         for v in view.subviews{
             if v is UIScrollView {
                 (v as! UIScrollView).delegate = self
             }
         }
     }

    .
    .
    .
}

extension YourViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate{

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        startOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    }

    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        var direction = 0 //scroll stopped

        if startOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x {
            direction = 1 //going right
        }else if startOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x {
            direction = -1 //going left
        }

        let positionFromStartOfCurrentPage = abs(startOffset - scrollView.contentOffset.x)
        let percent = positionFromStartOfCurrentPage /  self.view.frame.width

        //you can decide what to do with scroll
    }

}
```

Comment: This works only if you don't use 2 fingers in order to continue scrolling between pages. After you pass second page, this startOffset should be set to 0 but it's not the case

Comment: @nonolays how about setting startOffset to zero each time PageViewController requests for a view controller?

Comment: Is this code applied to the PageViewController or to the individual view within the PageViewController 'set'?

Comment: @fmz there is a view within the PageViewController but you cannot access it easily, so i assume it applied toPageViewController

Answer (score 10):

Similar to Christian's answer but a bit more Swift-like (and not unnecessarily continuing to loop through view.subviews):

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if let view = view as? UIScrollView {
        view.delegate = self
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 13, the `UIPageViewController` seems to reset the scrollview's contentOffset once it transitions to another view controller. Here is a working solution:

1. Find the child scrollView and set its delegate to self, as other answers suggested
2. Keep track of the current page index of the pageViewController:

```
var currentPageIndex = 0
// The pageViewController's viewControllers
let orderredViewControllers: [UIViewController] = [controller1, controller2, ...]

pageViewController.delegate = self

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    guard completed, let currentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first else { return }
    currentPageIndex = orderredViewControllers.firstIndex(of: currentViewController)!
}
```

3. Get the progress that ranges from 0 to 1

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let width = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let offset = CGFloat(currentPageIndex) / CGFloat(orderredViewControllers.count - 1)
    let progress = (contentOffsetX - width) / width + offset
}
```

Comment: Worked a couple of month for 2 pages but not for 3. Moving to the solution below.

Answer (score 3):

```
var pageViewController: PageViewController? {
    didSet {
        pageViewController?.dataSource = self
        pageViewController?.delegate = self
        scrollView?.delegate = self
    }
}

lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView? = {
    for subview in pageViewController?.view?.subviews ?? [] {
        if let scrollView = subview as? UIScrollView {
            return scrollView
        }
    }
    return nil
}()

extension BaseFeedViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let bounds = scrollView.bounds.width
    let page = CGFloat(self.currentPage)
    let count = CGFloat(viewControllers.count)
    let percentage = (offset - bounds + page * bounds) / (count * bounds - bounds)

    print(abs(percentage))
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the code as readable and separated as possible, I would define an extension on `UIPageViewController`:

```swift
extension UIPageViewController {
  var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
    view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) as? UIScrollView
  }
}
```

It's quite easy to set yourself as the `delegate` for scroll view events, as so:

```
pageViewController.scrollView?.delegate = self
```