# Tracking swipe movement in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm very new to Swift, and trying to create an app where Swiping between pages works normally but also involves a change in background color based on swipe distance.

Consequently, I want to "hijack" the swipe gesture, so I can add some behavior to it. The best I can find for how to do that is [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241356/get-scroll-position-of-uipageviewcontroller).

Translating the code from the chosen answer into Swift 3, I added the following code to my `RootViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` function:

```
    for subview in (pageViewController?.view.subviews)!{
        if let coercedView = subview as? UIScrollView {
            coercedView.delegate = (self as! UIScrollViewDelegate)
        }
    }
```

My impression was that the above code would let me `delegate` functions (such as `scrollViewDidScroll` to the class in which I'm writing the above code, such that I can define that function, call `super.scrollViewDidScroll`, and then add any other functionality I want.

Unfortunately, the above code, which doesn't throw any compilation errors, *does* throw an error when I try to build the app:

```
Could not cast value of type 'My_App.RootViewController' (0x102cbf740) to 'UIScrollViewDelegate' (0x1052b2b00).
```

Moreover, when I try to write `override func scrollViewDidScroll` in my class, I get a compilation error telling me the function doesn't exist to override, which makes me think even if I got past the error, it wouldn't get called, and this isn't the right way to handle this issue.

I'm sorry this is such a noobish question, but I'm really quite confused about the basic architecture of how to solve this, and whether I understand the given answer correctly, and what's going wrong.

Am I interpreting `delegate` and that answer correctly? 
Am I delegating to the correct object? (Is that the right terminology here?)
Is there a better way to handle this?
Am I coercing/casting improperly? Should I instead do:

```
view.delegate = (SomeHandMadeViewDelegateWhichDefinesScrollViewDidScroll as! UIScrollViewDelegate)
```

or something similar/different (another nested casting with `let coercedSelf = self as? UIScrollViewDelegate` or something?

Thanks!

Comment: "when I try to write `override func scrollViewDidScroll` ..." - Yeah, you only use `override` when the view controller's superclass implements that particular method. But it doesn't, so `override` is not appropriate. So, (a) declare your view controller to conform to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol; and (b) implement whichever `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods you want, with no `override` (unless your super class just happens to implement that particular method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to catch some scroll position and stuff right ? Then do

```
class RootViewController {
   // Your stuff

   for subview in pageViewController!.view.subviews {
     if let coercedView = subview as? UIScrollView {
      coercedView.delegate = self
     }
}

extension RootViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate {
   // Your scrollView stuff there
}
```

Comment: Yay! That worked perfectly. Mind confirming my impression of what's going on here, so I can understand it better? When I write the `extension` line, I'm extending `RootViewController` with the basic functionality of a `UIScrollViewDelegate`, which allows me to then `delegate` the `coercedView`'s behavior to the class itself. How would I then get the position etc from within, say, a `scrollViewDidScroll` function (which is being hit)?

Comment: Actually, I just figured out the position stuff. But would love a confirmation that I get the basic concepts, if you've got the time. Swift is really confusing at the moment.

Comment: Actually the extension isn't needed. You could just write class RootViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate and it would do the same. It's only there to make the code clearer.

Comment: I didn't expect to send my comment..  Anyway, let's finish. With this line (extension...) you are saying you will override some UIScrollView method (like scrollviewdidscroll). By setting the scrollview.delegate = self you are saying that your scrollview should use your overrided method. My explanations are so crap :D