# How to create swipe left/right tabs on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

How to create tabs on the screen and swipe left/right and it'll go to that corresponding screen. For example, it's something similar to Hulu's UI where you first start on the TV Shows tab and if you swipe left, you'll go to movies. The swipe is a holding swipe so it won't trigger unless you release it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `UIPageViewController` you can achieve your requirement.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller.

For moving line, you have to implement logic on scroll

[Get scroll position of UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241356/get-scroll-position-of-uipageviewcontroller)

If you are new to `UIPageViewController`, you can use some third parties which are easy to integrate.

https://github.com/topics/uipageviewcontroller